# How to get a click on the search view entry box?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, searchview

I have a search view (the little magnifying glass and the entry box) and want to be notified when a user clicks in the entry box.

If I attached a click listener to the search view it only triggers when the magnifying glass itself is clicked (tried same thing with touch, no diff).  I want it to trigger when the user clicks ANYWHERE in the search box.  What am I missing here?

Thanks

- Tab